# C# XML how to stop & from converted to &amp;

Tags: c#, xml

This is regarding C# VS 2012

```
using System.Xml.Linq;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            XElement xe = new XElement("entry", "&27&");
            Console.WriteLine(xe);
        }
    }
}
```

My user wants some bizarre entries in his xml input file where it involves 2 &s so he can execute his Linux shell scripts.  To keep this simple, when I do the above, I get this output:

```
<entry>&amp;27&amp;</entry>
```

but I want this output instead:

```
<entry>&27&</entry>
```

From what I've read, a single & will causing incorrect XML syntax so VS do this on purpose but I have 2 &s.  My user won't take

```
<entry>&amp;27&amp;</entry>
```

as input, he wants "&27&" so I'm stuck, please help.

Comment: You would have invalid xml.  The ampersand has special meaning in an xml so you need to replacement.  See : https://www.classe.cornell.edu/~dms79/LectureNotes/formulae/List%20of%20XML%20and%20HTML%20character%20entity%20references%20-%20Wikipedia,%20the%20free%20encyclopedia.htm

Comment: copied, understood about syntax requirement per your link.  However my end user's program tolerates this part of the syntax - he absolutely needs to have && in the attributes.  Which leaves me no choice but to work around this issue.  How do I work around this issue?

Comment: Use the substitution twice : &amp;&amp;

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on how he is reading the xml that you provided. As in your example the print on the console will show the escaped & character as you are printing the xml. If you print the value of the Xelement `Console.Writeline(xe.value);` you will see the expected outcome.

Your xml is completely perfect and as long as your customer is parsing the xml file with a proper xml parser he is able to get the attribute values in the desired format and use it.

Comment: I wish it's really that easy, I don't have access to his codes but I know this part works <shell exec="/exec/bin/copy &#x27;%FILE%&#27;"/>  if I enter &amp; for & it will ignore.  And yes you are right, when I look at my code in watch it generates &amp; output for actually showing & ...anyway, I know it's hard question but I'm stuck where the receiving end is not following xml 1.0 format.

Comment: I see this far to often here, customers that are breaking rules/contracts and developers looking for creative solutions to please the customer. have you considered sticking to the "can't do" answer and force him to change his scripts? I assume that he concats parts of the message into a string in his shell script. Why isn't he adding the & before and after the variable? Then you can send just value. it is a minor change on his side which helps both parties.